# Comparing data objects in python ValueError

Tags: python, datetime

I wrote a script that retrieves a date from a textfile, converts that to a `datetime` and checks if the current time is later than the datetime in the file. I wrote the following code for that:

```
from datetime import datetime

f = open("token.txt", "r")
expiry_date = f.readline()
f.close()

if datetime.now() >= datetime.strptime(expiry_date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f"):
    #DO STUFF
```

However, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: unconverted data remains:
```

Anyone knows where I went wrong and how I can fix this?

The line I want to retrieve from the textfile contains a date formatted like this:

```
2020-05-10 19:29:51.503962
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `readline()`, there is a `\n` appended to the line. strip the newline first.

Please try:

```
if datetime.now() >= datetime.strptime(expiry_date.strip(), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f"):
#DO STUFF
```

It will work.

Comment: First I want to retrieve the firstline to retrieve an expiry date for a token I set. After that I want to retrieve a token that I write to the second line

Comment: Ok, then please strip() the line, as shown in the answer. It should work.